# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT how to format Object to Array?

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, object

```
{
    "workingHours":
        [
            {
                "date":"2023-02-01",
                "amount":3,
                "freigegeben":false
            }
        ]
}
```

When I sent this in my request Body, I get the error in my title. How can I manually add [ and ], so it is an Array? Or how could I solve this?

This is the request I send:

```
public async saveWorkingHours(
    employeeId: string | null,
    workingHours: WorkingHours[]
  ): Promise<boolean> {

    var result = Object.entries(workingHours.map(wh => ({ ...wh, date: this.dateService.format(wh.date) })));
    try {
      await this.httpService.fetch(
        `${this.apiUrl}employees/${employeeId}/workingHours`,
        HttpMethod.PUT,
        {

          // This is my body, which starts with "{", instead of "[". That is the problem
          workingHours: workingHours.map(wh => ({ ...wh, date: this.dateService.format(wh.date) })),
        }
      );
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Workinghours interface:

```
export interface WorkingHours {
  date: Date;
  amount: number;
  freigegeben: boolean;
}
```

Doing so:

```
 var convertedFormatData = [];

    var tempObj = {
      workingHours: workingHours.map((wh) => ({
        ...wh,
        date: this.dateService.format(wh.date),
      })),
    };
    convertedFormatData.push(tempObj);
```

My Output looks like this:

```
{"convertedFormatData":[{"workingHours":[{"date":"2023-02-01","amount":3,"freigegeben":false},{ ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manually add"? In a text editor? In some programming language where you have existing code to generate? Please click [edit] and make your question more specific, remembering that we don't know anything about your code unless you show us.

Comment: I edited it. I meant, I tried edit the brackets into the variable in string format

Comment: OK, that's a lot better, although there are a couple of things that still aren't as clear as they could be: you haven't mentioned what programming language this is (that should be the first tag you add to any question); and it's not clear where you tried to put the brackets so far (what is "this" in "but this didn't work"?). It would also be great if you could rework this into a [mre], or at least give some idea what the `WorkingHours` type looks like.

Comment: Please forget the adding the brackets manually thing. It was just mentioned to make clear, thats what should be done, the problem is just how. I edited the rest. Please, take a look.

Comment: the problem is, that at the very beginning I need a "["

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BEGIN_ARRAY` is `[`, and `BEGIN_OBJECT` is `{`.

Here, you are starting with `{`, so for the website you seems to send an object, but he's waiting for a list. To send a list, you should do:

```json
[
   {
       "here": "is the json"
   }
]
```

So, for you, it should be something like this:

```json
[
   {
      "workingHours":[
         {
            "date":"2023-02-01",
            "amount":3,
            "freigegeben":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

There is few ways to make it as array:

```js
var test = {
  "workingHours":[
     {
        "date":"2023-02-01",
        "amount":3,
        "freigegeben":false
     }
  ]
};
console.log(test["workingHours"]);
```

Comment: Exactly thats what I meant with the [ and ]. But I dont know how to add them

Comment: var tempArray: [] = [workingHours];

this also doesn't work

Comment: var result: [] = [];
    result.push(workingHours.map(wh => ({ ...wh, date: this.dateService.format(wh.date) })));
Also doesn't work...

Comment: In the snippet I made, `[var]` is working, and pushing too. I suggest you to add the complete object and not only the key/value workingHours. You should check the request format to be sure about how you should send it

Comment: Idk why, but my output starts like: {"tempObj":[{. I edited my question to show you my part.

Comment: And what is the format require by the url that will receive the json ? what you should send ?

Comment: And maybe you can just send the result of `workingHours.map((wh) => ({  ...wh, date: this.dateService.format(wh.date) }))` which seems to be a list

Comment: The format requires this:
[
  {
        "date": "2023-02-01",
        "amount": 3,
        "freigegeben": false
    }
]

Comment: like just the objects, but covered in squared brackets

Comment: I could also just delete the first 12 characters, right?

Comment: I just edit my answer. Take the object you sent, then get values from it :) Remove characteres at begin and end will works, but it's a strange way to do something that should be fine

Comment: var tempObj = {workingHours: workingHours.map((wh) => ({
      ...wh,
      date: this.dateService.format(wh.date),
    }))};
and then tempObj["workingHours"] doesnt work. 
I get a ',' expected.ts(1005) in between tempObj and ["workingHours"]

Comment: or this  var tempObj = {"workingHours": workingHours.map((wh) => ({
      ...wh,
      date: this.dateService.format(wh.date),
    }))};

Comment: for console.log it works, but it isnt being accepted as a body param

Comment: Can you log the `tempObj`